# Listening for wave out in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows

So I want to "listen" to the output to sound devices in windows. Preferably in C/C++. I have no idea what a proper starting point would be for this on windows and was wondering if I could get pointed in the right direction to capture sound. I would like to do this so that I can change different settings based on the sound that is playing. I am not looking to listen through a microphone

Comment: Oh you think I didn't do that eh?

Comment: You have not provided any evidence of doing it, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to work with Windows audio related COM-based interfaces. Starting point is to obtain a reference to the `IMMDevice` interface of an endpoint object in a device collection by calling the `IMMDeviceCollection::Item` method. Afterwards, it is possible to get a reference to the `IMMEndpoint` interface of an endpoint object by calling the IMMDevice::QueryInterface` method. After retrieving a collection of endpoint devices, it is possible to query the properties of the individual devices in the collection to determine their suitability for use.

This is [one example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678711.aspx) and [this is another](https://github.com/rdp/virtual-audio-capture-grabber-device/blob/master/source_code/synth_deprecated/loopback-capture.cpp)

Comment: Perfect this is just the starting point for my research that I needed. Thank you very much